# Explain a statement in C#

Tags: c#

I am working my way through a book called Head First C#. It doesnt explain what the loop is saying in detail. It would be great if someone can explain the part I dont understand.
The way I am reading this is as long as c is less than 254 and visible c will increase by 1 each time the loop is gone through. What I dont understand is the (c, 255 - c, c)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        while (Visible)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 254 && Visible; c++)
            {
                this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(c, 255 - c, c);
                Application.DoEvents();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: On a side note, though this works well to help show a behavior running continuously in the UI, it's a very bad idea to use DoEvents like this in real code.  Be sure to bear in mind that this is example code and not representative of a good way to create background color animation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(c, 255 - c, c);
```

[The arguments to that function are `red, green, blue`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVsFE.gif) The maximum value is 255 and the minimum value is 0. This function fades the color from full green into no green, full red-blue (magenta).

```
for (int c = 0; c < 254 && Visible; c++)
```

The loop will continue until either the form is made invisible (assuming this event handler is on a form, `Visible` refers to `this.Visible` and will be false if the form is hidden), or the maximum value is reached (`c < 254` will be false).

Here's a chart that shows the common colors based on their red, green, and blue values. In the chart, the format is `RRGGBB`, where `RR` is the red value, `GG` is the green value, and `BB` is the blue value. The numbers are in hex (runs from 0 to FF instead of 0 to 255).

[image]

Comment: Just as an aside, 'Visible' is just a boolean value. Nothing listed indicates that it is related to the 'Visible' property of the button itself. So a more specific terminator would be until the boolean 'Visible' is changed to false by some action.

Comment: Good catch, and actually I was wrong anyway -- by default this would refer to form visibility and not button visibility.

Answer (score 4):

So it's this statement that you don't understand, right?

```
this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(c, 255 - c, c);
```

That's setting the `BackColor` property to the value returned from the [`Color.FromArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557.aspx) method. The arguments to that method are `c`, `255 - c`, and `c`. So for example, if `c` is 100, it will call `Color.FromArgb(100, 155, 100)`.

Basically this is animating the background colour from green (0, 255, 0) to purple (253, 2, 253). It's doing it in a pretty nasty way, using `Application.DoEvents` and making the UI thread sleep, but hopefully the book will explain a nicer approach over time :)

Comment: when will the loop end or will it end

Comment: @randywhite30 - it will end when either c >= 254 or the boolean value "Visible" is changed to false by some action

Comment: I thought I was missing something I let it run for about 5 minutes and it was still going

Comment: @randywhite30, the outer loop will only end if Visible becomes false.

Comment: @Dan: What's stopping `c` from becoming 254, and the loop terminating that way?

Comment: @Jon, there's an outer `while (Visible)` loop

Comment: @Dan: Doh, didn't see that bit :)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about what will happen to 'c' as the loop iterates.  The line you are having trouble with is creating a different color from the value of 'c' on each iteration.  Thus, the backcolor of the form will change as c changes.

Answer (score 1):

The description of the behavior is wrong.

This routine will continually slide the color from green to purple and then reset it to green and do it again.  The only way the loop exits is if the button turns invisible in response to something that is executed by the DoEvents() call.